# Копирование данных модели

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Делаю обычный CRUD контроллер. Просто не делал этого на ASP раньше. Вот я загрузил модель допустим:

```
[HttpPost("update")]
public async Task Update(int id, [FromBody] Person newModel)
{
    using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        var model = await db.Persons.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstAsync();
    }
}
```

Подскажите как мне теперь данные перекинуть из модели полученной запросом в модель которую я достал из базы? Можно конечно просто присвоить все поля вручную, но мне кажется или это такое себе решение? А если бы у меня полей было 10+? Неудобно же...

Comment: [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)

Answer (score 0):

EntityFramework отслеживает состояние всех своих объектов во внутренних списках и реагирует на них. Надо EntityFramework сказать явно переписать состояние внутреннего объекта на внешний. Делается это методом Attach:

```
[HttpPost("update")]
public async Task Update(int id, [FromBody] Person newModel)
{
   using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
   {        
     db.Persons.Attach(newModel);
     db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(newModel, EntityState.Modified);
     await db.SaveChangesAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: Нет такого свойства `ObjectStateManager`. Зачем это вообще? Разве `Attach` сам не меняет состояние?

Comment: добавьте using System.Data.Objects;

Comment: Attach меняет состояние объекта в Unchanged. Следующей строкой Вы  меняете состояние объекта в Modified. Если Вы используете EF.Core  вы можете просто использовать метод контекста Update. db.Update(newModel)